# disable writing of character on qtextedit by overriding keypress event in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4, keypress

Is it possible to disable writing of characters on qtextedit  by overriding keypress event in pyqt4 python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from `QTextEdit` and overwrite the corresponding event handler methods:

```
class MyTextEdit(QTextEdit):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
```